# NSString from App Delegate Not Retaining Value When Recall In View Controller (iOS)

Tags: xcode, delegates, nsstring, uilabel

I cannot for the life of me, figure out why I can't set an NSString located in my app delegate and then recall it in a different view controller.

What I've done is set up annotations on a MKMapView. I used the calloutAccessoryControlTapped method to push the View Controller to "DetailsViewController." In DetailsViewController, I display the title and subtitle from the annotation as UILabels on the page (it's basically a title and an address). Since there are only two values you can set in the annotation (title and subtitle) and I also want to display the phone number of the locations in the DetailsViewController, I decided to set the phone number as an NSString in the app delegate. Then, I would recall that value in DetailsViewController as a UILabel.

I've created and synthesized the NSString in the app delegate as "phoneNumber."

Then I imported the app delegates .h file into implementation file I'm working with.

For some reason, it won't secure the value that I set to it though. I've tried to log it out from numerous spots and it doesn't work. When I call the calloutAccesoryControlTapped method and try to log the value of the phone number it's (null). When I open the DetailsViewController for any annotation it only returns one specific phone number, no matter which one I click. So, without further ado, here's the code:

LocationsViewController .m:

```
//Miller's Neighborhood Market #9
MillersLocations *ann09 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
ann09.title = @"Neighborhood Market #9";
ann09.subtitle = @"1700 Todds Lane, Hampton, VA 23666";
ann09.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.0395580, -76.4096930);
[mapView addAnnotation:ann09];
[ann09 release];
delegate.phoneNumber = @"(757) 826-7608";

//Miller's Neighborhood Market #10
MillersLocations *ann10 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
ann10.title = @"Neighborhood Market #10";
ann10.subtitle = @"2722 Airline Blvd., Portsmouth, VA 23701";
ann10.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.8110840, -76.3644950);
[mapView addAnnotation:ann10];
[ann10 release];
delegate.phoneNumber = @"(757) 488-0223";

//Miller's Neighborhood Market #16
MillersLocations *ann16 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
ann16.title = @"Neighborhood Market #16";
ann16.subtitle = @"3801 Indian River Rd., Chesapeake, VA 23325";
ann16.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.822247, -76.233070);
[mapView addAnnotation:ann16];
[ann16 release];
delegate.phoneNumber = @"(757) 420-1866";

//Miller's Neighborhood Market #21
MillersLocations *ann21 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
ann21.title = @"Neighborhood Market #21";
ann21.subtitle = @"2129 W. Mercury Blvd., Hampton, VA 23666";
ann21.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.0385289, -76.4004810);
[mapView addAnnotation:ann21];
[ann21 release];
delegate.phoneNumber = @"(757) 826-5237";

//Miller's Neighborhood Market #23
MillersLocations *ann23 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
ann23.title = @"Neighborhood Market #23";
ann23.subtitle = @"13797 Warwick Blvd., Newport News, VA 23602";
ann23.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.124062, -76.531425);
[mapView addAnnotation:ann23];
[ann23 release];
delegate.phoneNumber = @"(757) 874-5806";
```

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be releasing these values after every time I set them. Ok and then here is how I try to call them in the DetailsViewController.m:

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
    Miller_Tab_BarAppDelegate *delegate = (Miller_Tab_BarAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    delegate.phoneNumber=phoneLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@", delegate.phoneNumber);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"tel:%@", phoneLabel.text]]];
}
```

Every single time it logs out (no matter which annotation I use to push the view controller) it always displays the number for location #23. I can't figure out why it's displaying that number AND why it won't change the value? Anybody have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: This comment has nothing to do with your question, but you should definitely use a plist to store your array of contact informations rather than hard coding them into the app.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here. You're setting a single value multiple times, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'm obviously still starting out and have been reading a bit about plists, maybe it's about time for me to dive in...

Comment: No, I'm trying to set it once with the click of the annotation button and display it.

Comment: Maybe my head's a little scrambled and I'm thinking of it backwards.

Comment: You're setting delegate.phoneNumber with each item, and therefore resetting the variable to that value. delegate.phoneNumber can only contain one value.

Answer (score 0):

visit this page, he uses multiple annotations and uses a for loop to place 5 of them

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/804_Introduction_to_MapKit_Framework_for_iPhone_Development.aspx

Hope this helps

J

Comment: This is different than what I'm talking about up there. I'm not having trouble placing the pins, it's controlling the content of the Details View Controller that's called when you click the callout accessory button in the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate.h file, `#define appd (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`

(This is a shorthand macro. "AppDelegate" everywhere here should be replaced with the name of your appdelegate class.)

In your viewcontroller, change the object with `[appd setPhoneNumber:@"705-123 456"]; //note how the first letter p becomes P when prefixed with 'set'.`

If you still have trouble, you should create `AppDelegate *appdel=appd;` where you set the phone number, set a breakpoint there and check that phoneNumber and appdel is initalized properly. (Hover over variable name, Print Description to console.)